# Glassfish admin console slow loading

Tags: glassfish-3

Today I stopped/started my GlassfishV3 instance and now I cannot access the addmin console located at http://servername:4848/. The screen says:  "**The admin console is loading...**" This is going on forever now.

I have tried as follows:

- I have tried adding the following entry to my **domain.xml** located at **/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config** as suggested in another Stack Overflow Q&A but after restarting the server still no luck.

  `<java-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.NO_NETWORK=true</java-options>`
- I have also installed glassfishv3 on my local machine and cannot recreate the problem.I can go to http://localhost:4848 without any problem.
- I have also looked at the **server.log** and **jvm.log** files located under the **/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs** and nothing there that shed some light.

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Setting the java-option to NO_NETWORK to true did not work so I upgraded from 3.0.1 to 3.1 and it got fixed. Not immediately though, I had to stop/start the Glassfish server a couple of times before I got into the admin console without any really long delays.

**Solution**

The solution was to upgrade from the command line using the pkg utility.

You can find the steps in this link: 
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2437/gkthu.html#gktjf

Or do as follows:

1. Go to as-install-parent/bin
2. ./pkg image-update
3. as-install-parent/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain --upgrade domain-name
4. as-install-parent/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain domain-name

**UPDATE**
I had peformance issues again and I found this other solution in Joshi's tech blog:
http://joshitech.blogspot.com/2009/09/glassfish-application-server.html

Basically add the following jvm options in the domain.xml. It should increase Glassfish boot up and deployment performance:

```
<jvm-options>-server</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xms3000m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-Xmx3000m</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=192m</jvm-options> 
<jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options> 
<jvm-options>-XX:+AggressiveHeap</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+AggressiveOpts</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+UseParallelGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:+UseParallelOldGC</jvm-options>
<jvm-options>-XX:ParallelGCThreads=5</jvm-options>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar symptoms, and I tried some of what Dario had suggested as well, but it didn't work.  It could be that I had a unique configuration for my dev env: I'm running Glassfish 3.1 on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit guest on a Windows 7 64-bit host.   Quite by accident, I discovered an additional symptom: if I turned off the network on the Ubuntu guest, the console would load successfully on a localhost browser instance.  That is, on the Ubuntu guest with the network off, I could successfully navigate to http://localhost:4848 and show the Glassfish admin console as expected.  However, if the Ubuntu guest's network was on, I had the exact behavior suggested by the original poster: http://localhost:4848 would just sit forever on the inial loading page.

To make a long story short, I found that adding the following argument to the JVM options for server-config fixed the problem:
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

When I made that change and restarted the Glassfish server, everything worked.

(Note that I also had in place some of the other settings recommended above, i.e., NO_NETWORK=true, and I'd adjusted the JVM memory footprint and set it to -server instead of -client.  It could be that these settings are required as well, though they weren't sufficient on their own in my case.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for contributing to the cause!!

Answer (score 2):

I was having this exact same problem. I could deploy in run mode, but it would hang forever in Debug mode. IntelliJ was hanging on the **breakpoints**. I muted the breakpoints, and glassfish3 worked good as new. I didn't have to change any domain.xml settings. **Check your breakpoints!**

Comment: Same issue here. Just removed all eclipse breakpoints and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278876/why-is-the-glassfish-admin-console-so-slow/5281931#5281931), but there is a second step described (disabling update module).

Two more ideas:

1. Check if the `NO_NETWORK=true` option really works (there should be no ads in GF admin console)
2. Watch the *server.log* (glassfish-install-dir/glassfis/domains/domain1/logs) during startup and look for the last log entry before the delay occurs. This could be a hint for the source of the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the response Matt. What you suggested is what I had done and did not work either. I found a solution, which was basically to upgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.1. See below

Answer (score 0):

Beware of blindly following Dario's example unless you've lots more RAM than most do.

-Xms3000m gives 3gb to Glassfish. Do YOU have that much spare RAM?

I tried this on my 4gb Mac with 1gb for Glassfish. Made no discernable difference at all...performance still sux.

Comment: Hi Bradjcox, This is better suited for enterprise settings, QA or Production servers. If you want to do web development on a local machine I would recommend Tomcat unless you need the features of fullblown app server. Also, the issues Im reporting I am not having them in my local environment, which is less powerful than an enterprise environment, but where it really matters, at work :)

Comment: Yeah, might try that. Another option that looked promising this weekend is to stick with GF but avoid its high-end features (particularly SOA/JAX-WS) and use nothing but servlets and JAX-B. Have lost all patience with latest Sun/Oracle/Java6+ "features".