# Disable automatic updates check in Glassfish

Tags: testing, glassfish, glassfish-3

We are using Glassfish for several projects. I would like to completely disable the update checks at startup since they make testing difficult in low-bandwidth scenario.

We are doing automatic testing with both Glassfish in embedded mode as well as automatically configuring a new domain, starting the server and testing with server running normally.

Since all the tests are completely automatic all the solutions I found involving the admin interface are not practicable.

BTW: we are using Glassfish 3.1.2

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this discussion](http://www.mentby.com/Group/glassfish-users/glassfish-v3-admin-console-very-slow.html) referenced in [one of my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5281931/620338). There are some options discussed.

If I remember correctly, one of them was about renaming the particular module in the GF modules dir. But it is a kind of lenghty discussion there. Hope you get some hints!

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a 'cleaner' solution than deleting the module but it works and seems to have no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

**asadmin> create-jvm-options -Dcom.sun.enterprise.tools.admingui.NO_NETWORK=true**

This is documented here:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24928/extending-updating.htm

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works for the Admin GUI but not if you start Glassfish from the command line or if you use it in Embedded mode.